# Python different errors with image upload and OCR response depending on image

Tags: python, image, parsing, flask, ocr

I am using a flask server to handle image uploads, sending the data to OCR Space API, and using the text response for a project I am working on in python. I have been receiving different errors based on what image of a receipt I upload. The code works with other images just fine. For example if the images are uploaded to ocr.space, saved as the string `OCRText`, and used in my program, these images return `IndexError: list index out of range`[image]

[image][image]
These images return `flask_uploads.UploadNotAllowed`
[image][image]
This image returns `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2.99'`
[image]
And these images return `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`. [image][image]
These errors are causing a big problem in my code and I have been trying for a while to resolve them. Any help solving any of the problems will be greatly appreciated!

Full Index Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\OCR - Copy\OCRWebsite\app.py", line 442, in upload
    GetItemPricesandNumbers()
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\OCR - Copy\OCRWebsite\app.py", line 103, in GetItemPricesandNumbers
    try_shorten = re.findall(".+\n(?=SUBTOTAL)", txt, re.DOTALL)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Index Error code:

```
`global itemprices
global itemnumberslist
txt = OCRText
num_re = re.compile(r"(?<=\s)(?:(?:\d+\.)?\d+)(?=[\s])")
try_shorten = re.findall(".+\n(?=SUBTOTAL)", txt, re.DOTALL)[0]
if try_shorten: txt = try_shorten
txt = re.sub(r"(.+)", r" \g<1> ", txt)
itemprices = {}
itemnumberslist = []
for i in txt.splitlines():
    matches = num_re.findall(i)
    if len(matches) != 2: continue
    itemprices[int(matches[0])] = float(matches[1])
    #itemprices.append({int(matches[0]): float(matches[1])})
    itemnumberslist.append(int(matches[0]))
print(itemprices)
print(itemnumberslist)`
```

Upload not Allowed Full Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\OCR - Copy\OCRWebsite\app.py", line 417, in upload
    file_name = photos.save(request.files['photo'])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask_uploads.py", line 416, in save
    raise UploadNotAllowed()
flask_uploads.UploadNotAllowed
```

Flask upload not allowed code:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and 'photo' in request.files:
#return render_template('loading.html')
global file_name
file_name = photos.save(request.files['photo'])
print(file_name)
global file_path
file_path = os.path.join(r'PATH', file_name)
print(file_path)
```

Value Error Full Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\OCR - Copy\OCRWebsite\app.py", line 442, in upload
    GetItemPricesandNumbers()
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\OCR - Copy\OCRWebsite\app.py", line 111, in GetItemPricesandNumbers
    itemprices[int(matches[0])] = float(matches[1])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2.99'
```

Value Error code:

```
itemprices = {}
itemnumberslist = []
for i in txt.splitlines():
    matches = num_re.findall(i)
    if len(matches) != 2: continue
    itemprices[int(matches[0])] = float(matches[1])
    #itemprices.append({int(matches[0]): float(matches[1])})
    itemnumberslist.append(int(matches[0])
print(itemprices)
print(itemnumberslist)
```

Type Error Full Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\OCR - Copy\OCRWebsite\app.py", line 437, in upload
    parsed_results = result.get("ParsedResults")[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Type Error:

```
url_api = "https://api.ocr.space/parse/image"
    result = requests.post(url_api,
                    files = {os.path.join(r'PATH', file_name): file_bytes},
                    data = {"apikey": "KEY",
                            "language": "eng",
                            #"OCREngine": 2,
                            "isTable": True})
    result = result.content.decode()
    result = json.loads(result)
    #print(result)
    parsed_results = result.get("ParsedResults")[0]
```

Comment: Please show us the complete stack trace. It'll have the clues we need.

Comment: Hello, I have updated my question to include the complete error messages for each problem I am facing.

Answer (score 1):

```
re.findall(".+\n(?=SUBTOTAL)", txt, re.DOTALL)
```

will return an empty list if it can't match at least one non-empty line. E.g.,

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(".+\n(?=SUBTOTAL)", "\n", re.DOTALL)
[]
```

When your code tries to get the 0'th item, Python raises an `IndexError`. The issue to debug is why the list is empty. And for that you'll need to take a closer look at `OCRText`.

```
>>> int('2.99')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2.99'
```

is exactly as that: `int()` only converts strings that represent integers. Now did you end up with '2.99' instead of an item code? Again, inspecting the OCR output directly might provide a clue.

Rather than involving Flask at this point, you might get better traction by feeding the images to OCR and saving the output, taking a close look at that output, and then separately testing your code against saved output, adjusting your code as you go. I suspect you'll find the OCR service doesn't do a perfect job (especially given scribbles on the receipts), and that some of your regular expressions aren't doing what you expect when they encounter those errors.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the help! A sample OCRText for the first image on Index Error would be: `OMAHA, NE #1012 
12300, West Dodge Rd
Omaha, NE 68154
MEMBER #111779751435
134991 0RGANIC PAST
172246 PELED CAROTS
27664 IOF STRWBRYS      8.99
5623 BROCCOLI   4.79
4032 MAJERMELON 5.99
15994 CANTALOUPE        5.49
88426 CUCUMBERS 3.29
30669 BANANAS   1.47
91698 RED EPPERS        7.49
38180 ORGNC BS THG
39036 ROMAINE   3       79
TOTAL`

Comment: Good. Save that in a file, and use it to debug your regular expressions.

Comment: Ok the Index Error is fixed in my program